# Symfony Collections cannot retrieve collection values in controller

Tags: php, symfony

i have a entity MyEntity with a collection of langues.

For langue we have two fields (langues and niveaux)
Below is how I add the collection to my form.

```
 ->add('langues', CollectionType::class, 
            array(
            'entry_type' => LangueparleeType::class,
            'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'allow_delete'  => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'prototype'     => true,
            ))
```

Nowto display the collection from form  to another twig for prining :

```
{% for langue in candidat.langues %}  
       <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
          <label class="font-weight-bold" > Langues </label>  <input class="form-control"  value = "{{ langue.langues }}" />
       </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
          <label class="font-weight-bold" > Langues </label>  <input class="form-control"  value = "{{ langue.niveaux }}" />
       </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

I can just get the first value (langues) but not niveaux

Comment: Which version of Symfony are you using ?

Comment: @gogaz Symfony 3.4

Comment: You don't seem to be using the {{ form(form.langues) }} directive, why ?
From a form you could get them with {{ form.vars.data.langues }} or something similar